# Does timestamp of a file in /proc filesystem indicate the time at which parameter sample is taken?

Tags: linux, proc

Does timestamp of a file in /proc filesystem indicate the time at which parameter sample is taken ? if not, how to get timestamp at which a parameter is updated in a file under /proc ?

Comment: Of what parameter and what exact `/proc/` file are you thinking about? Please edit your question to improve it.

Comment: Any file in under /proc

Comment: But it is not the same for all `/proc/` files, so you better edit your question to improve it. Which "parameter sample" are you thinking about?

Answer (score 0):

In general, **you should not trust that much the result of [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) on `/proc/` pseudo-files**, and that includes both the apparent file size and its modification or access times. It is well known that many `/proc/` files have a zero-size (as returned by `stat`) but a non-empty content (so should be read sequentially, like you would read a pipe), e.g. `/proc/self/maps`

Read more about [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), and also [Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) in your kernel source tree.

Indeed, some files appear to have a timestamp related to the (current) time of `open`-ing or `stat`-ing (e.g. `/proc/self/maps` or `/proc/$$/mounts` or `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`) but other files have a timestamp related to boot time, e.g `/proc/interrupts`

The `/proc/` file system is really arcane, *the ultimate reference about it is the kernel source code*. But I won't rely on the fact that parameter-like files (I guess that you speak of files like `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` ...) have a meaningful mtime.

Of course, the kernel does not keep track about modification times of many of its parameters.